# Layout_weight is not working as desired when using a nested LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I want to get my LinearLayout to display views in the desired proportion. I have perused some 10 or 15 other questions about LinearLayout and layout_weight, but for some reason no answers seem to apply in my case. I am creating a custom AlertDialog color-picker with a custom View created as follows:

```
private LinearLayout createLayout() {
    //Create our top-level layout
    LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    mainLayout.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 0);
    //Make the preset view at the top
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams presetViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.2f);
    mainLayout.addView(new PresetView(mContext), presetViewParams);
        //Create another linear layout
        LinearLayout subLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        subLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        subLayout.setPadding(0, 15, 0, 15);
        //Add the Sat Lum View to the second layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams satLumViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.60f);
        subLayout.addView(new SatLumView(mContext), satLumViewParams);
        //Add the divider between the sat lum view and the hue view
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams dividerViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.1f);
        subLayout.addView(new DividerView(mContext), dividerViewParams);
        //Add the Hue View to the second layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams hueViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.30f);
        subLayout.addView(new HueView(mContext), hueViewParams);
        //Add the second layout to the first layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams subLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.7f);
        mainLayout.addView(subLayout, subLayoutParams);
    //Add the Line view at the bottom of the main layout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lineParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.1f);
    mainLayout.addView(new LineView(mContext), lineParams);
    //Return our completed layout
    return mainLayout;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that despite having set the layout_height of my three vertical elements (PresetView, subLayout, and LineView) to `0`, the weight is still not distributing the available space how I want. subLayout does not get 70% of the space, but always less.

From what I can tell, the PresetView is always getting as much vertical space as it asks for, and subLayout and LineView are left to take up the remaining. Here is my `onMeasure()` method for PresetView:

```
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = resolveSize(250, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = resolveSize(150, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
```

The 250 and 150 are rather arbitrary values - the PresetView is designed to work with just about any set of dimensions (because I want the LinearLayout to control its size!).

I was under the impression that using a layout_height of 0 and specifying a weight put the layout in control of the space taken up by the View, rather than the View controlling it. Why is the PresetView still taking up a full 150 pixels, when I set it's layout_height to 0?

The `onMeasure()` method of the other Views is identical to PresetView's, only with different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was overriding onMeasure() improperly. The route that I took is useful if the View has predefined measurements (you KNOW that it will be 250 x 150 pixels). However, since I wanted my Views to scale to fit any screen size and be controlled completely by their layouts, all that I needed to do was use the default onMeasure() implementation:

```
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

This allows the layout_weight attribute to handle all sizing of the child Views.